# Play 2.6 => url encoding issue

Tags: java, playframework

In play 2.6, the WSClient.url(url) is encoding the URL as below:
https://localhost:1234/mypage/request?id=exact%25123&startR=1
Here the %25 is added to my URL.

```
I am using javaWS in build.sbt

import play.libs.ws.*;

@Inject WSClient ws;
WSRequest wsReq = ws.url(getUrl());
```

This was not the issue when i was using play 2.5 and the code was WS.url(url).
Can you please help in solving this.

Thanks

Comment: That seems to be correct, percent signs in the query part of the URL need to be percent encoded. The "%12" in your original URL would represent a special control character, which is probably not what you want. Maybe you should start with describing your problem, what does not work? Are you sending the request to a broken HTTP service?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your configuration:

```
play.ws.ahc.disableUrlEncoding = true
```